# MySQL: How to build polygin with radius/center of certain point?

Tags: mysql, geometry, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

I have a MySQL table containing longitude/latitude of places stored in a POINT data type with name `lonlat`(POINT data type).

Also I have a column with name `area` with `POLYGON` MySQL data type.

I want to fill `area` column with rectangle polygon with radius (for example 100 meters) of `lonlat` column that `lonlat` is center of this rectangle polygon.

How can I do this with an update command? I want query like this but how I can fill area?

```
UPDATE places SET area={?}
```

Note: MySQL version is 5.7

Comment: Inscribed or circumscribed?

Comment: circumscribed square polygon

Answer (score 0):

After tries , i found this code , but it build **diamond** with radius of 15 meters of `lonlat` cordinate:

```
update places set area=ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(concat( 'POLYGON((', ST_X(lonlat)+0.000135,' ',ST_Y(lonlat) ,',', ST_X(lonlat),' ',ST_Y(lonlat)-0.000135 ,',', ST_X(lonlat)-0.000135,' ',ST_Y(lonlat) ,',', ST_X(lonlat),' ',ST_Y(lonlat)+0.000135 , ',', ST_X(lonlat)+0.000135,' ',ST_Y(lonlat) ,'))'))
```

Comment: value of 0.000135 degree is equal to 15 meters